# Autotable create Nested table No Write DATA

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Hi all the nested table does not write the data inside, but leaves it in the main cell. what am I doing wrong ???

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l','mm','a3');          
        doc.autoTable({
        theme: 'grid',      
        columns: columns,    
        body: rows,    
        didDrawCell: function (data) {                      
            if (data.column.raw.displayEvent && data.cell.section === 'body') {                                   
                var EventData = data.cell.text;               
                doc.autoTable({                 
                    columns: miniColumns,         
                    body:EventData,       
                    didParseCell: function(dataEvent) {                     
                      if (dataEvent.column.raw.displayEvent === 'Opt'){                
                          dataEvent.row.styles.textColor = [255,0,0]
                        } 
                      },
                    startY: data.cell.y + 2,
                    margin: {left: data.cell.x + data.cell.padding('left')},
                    tableWidth: 'wrap',                
                    styles: {
                        fontSize: 7,
                        cellPadding: 0.5,
                    },
                    columnStyles: {
                            Icona: {cellWidth: 8},
                            Title: {cellWidth: 8},
                            Note:  {cellWidth: 8},                    
                            Opt:   {cellWidth: 8},                          
                     }
                });                        
            }
        },  

    });
```

My Complete Example

https://jsfiddle.net/max1974/bnLt6xsg/791/

Comment: Help me please.

Comment: I believe this is a JS BUG.
In my data I have =  "{'Note':'Notes7', 'title':'title7', 'Icona':'fas fa-user', 'Opt':'No'}"
But in EvenData I have this result = ["{'Note':'Notes7', 'title':'title7',", "'Icona':'fas fa-user',", "'Opt':'No'}"]
It inserts quotes and commas without any sense